# Designing operation (a,b) -> (c,d)

Tags: objective-c, oop

I have an operation that I need to design. That operation takes two objects of a certain class X, and returns two new objects of the same class (I may need the originals later). The logic that dictates the selection of this object is contained in class Y. On one hand, I don't want class Y to know details about class X implementation; on the other, I don't want class X to know details about selecting the different objects to perform this operation on.

If that was all the problem, I'd just create a static method on class A. However, the methods in language I'm working on return only one object. Also, the operation needs to be robust, and calling operation two times to get C and D respectively isn't possible, as both C & D both rely on a single random number.

How should I design such operation?

Update: I'm using Obejctive C.

Comment: Maybe if you tell us the language you are using it might help

Comment: Maybe you can create a Mapper that takes the X information and turns it into a Y object, have the Y object do internal map, and then turn it back into an X object. If you aren't more specific we can't really help you. :(

Comment: Objective C. @DonalFellows isn't creating an array just to return two elements will be too slow?

Comment: @golergka How often will this operation be called? "too slow" only really matters in bottlenecks. You're already creating two heap objects, allocating a further 8-16 more bytes won't change much.

Comment: @millimoose it's a crossover operation in genetic programming tool I'm writing, so I think that it'll be called a lot and can pretty easy become a bottleneck.

Comment: @golergka The other part of my point still remains: Will allocating the array be noticeable overhead compared to constructing the two objects you're returning in it?

Comment: @millimoose actually, I don't know ;). I decided to settle with an ugly solution for now (my answer below), but it won't have an overhead for array creation.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just modify given objects A & B with a static method. I'll have to make copies of them before calling this method, but I think it'll be not slower than creating new ones; most of the information in objects C & D is derived from A & B anyway.

(I still think it's an ugly solution, and will welcome a more qualified answer).